# Get element position relative to screen. (Or alternative solution)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I am aware this had been asked before, but no answer actually did the trick as far as I tested them.

Basically what I need is to change some element styles as soon as it "hits" the top border of the screen while scrolling down. This element is a 'Back to Top' button that will be sitting in a section and start following the user when they scroll pass said section.

I am not asking about CSS properties, I am asking about some JS property or method that allow me to know this. IE:

```
$('#back').distanceFromTopOfTheScreen()  // This value will decrease as I scroll down
```

I know there are other soultions, but the client has asked for this behavior.

Any idea?

Comment: `Element.getBoundingClientRect().top` check against it.

Comment: Get element position, get scroll position... Subtract... what is hard?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can :

```
  distance = $('#eleId')[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

For more about `getBoundingClientRect()` look at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) Documentation

**Note:** This value change when you're scrolling, it gives you the distance between the top border of the element and the top of the Page

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes JQuery make's everything more confusing than Native Javascript, even forgothing the very basics functions:

```
window.onscroll = function() { fixPosition()};
function fixPosition() {
    var Yplus = 4; //number of lines in every scroll
    document.getElementById('element').style.top = document.body.scrollTop + Yplus ;
}
```

This will allows you to move an "element" static on the window following the scroll.